# backbone.js how to set el to specific div id

Tags: backbone.js

My understanding of the Backbone View is that each html element that needs to show model data can be a View by itself.

I wish to create view linked to a specific div to show model data.
My problem is that the code doesn't work if I use anything else than 'body' for el.

Following code does not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/GhaPF/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ToDo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { "date": "today",
                "task": ""
            },
    initialize: function() {}
});

var ToDoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ToDo
});

var ToDoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#view1",
    initialize: function(myTodoList) {
        this.todolist = myTodoList;
        this.todolist.bind('add', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        text = this.todolist.toJSON();
        string = JSON.stringify(text);
        $(this.el).append(string);
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter"
    },
    createOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      if (!$("#new-todo").val()) return;
      this.todolist.add({"task": $("#new-todo").val()});
      $("#new-todo").val('');
    }
});

$("#new-todo").focus();
var todolist = new ToDoList();
var myToDoListView = new ToDoListView(todolist);
```

});
​

But if I use 'body' for el, it works as I want.

How can I set the el to a specific div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "#view1"

```
"keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter"
```

is not binded, because #new-todo is not within "#view1". Check [API](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).

Answer (score 7):

solution 
http://jsfiddle.net/r3F8q/

you can also use `this.setElement('#body1')` in render

```
<div id="view-container">
    <input id="new-todo" placeholder="text">
    <div id="view1"></div>
    <div id="view2"></div>
</div>
```

​

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var ToDo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { "date": "today",
                "task": ""
            },
    initialize: function() {}
});

var ToDoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ToDo
});

var ToDoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#view-container",
    initialize: function(myTodoList) {
        this.todolist = myTodoList;
        this.todolist.bind('add', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        text = this.todolist.toJSON();
        string = JSON.stringify(text);
        this.$el.find('#view1').append(string);
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter"
    },
    createOnEnter: function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      if (!$("#new-todo").val()) return;
      this.todolist.add({"task": $("#new-todo").val()});
      $("#new-todo").val('');
    }
});

$("#new-todo").focus();
var todolist = new ToDoList();
var myToDoListView = new ToDoListView(todolist);
});
```

​